# other user to access container (rootless docker daemon)

Tags: docker, rootless

Below is the problem description :

- Follow the below link to setup rootless docker daemon (say user+group name "nonroot" is used for starting docker daemon)

> https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/

- Add another user say "acme" and run "usermod -aG nonroot acme"
- from user "acme", run "export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/1001/docker.sock"
- from  user "acme" , run "docker ps -a", it returns "permission denied" (below is an example)

`Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///run/user/1001/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Frun%2Fuser%2F1001%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/json?all=1": dial unix /run/user/1001/docker.sock: connect: permission denied`

How do we achieve in order to allow other user to run docker command that is running on nonroot docker daemon ? yes, if we run "id acme", it does show "nonroot" group included.

Comment: Be sure to logout and login again after adding yourself to the "nonroot" group.

Answer (score 0):

After researching and googling, below link helps

> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socket

pre-requisite :
run "cd /run/user && chmod -R G+rwx 1001" or wherever the "docker.sock" and docker.pid exists.